# How to hide an element after its opacity get equal to 0?

Tags: css, vue.js

Is it possible to change display of an element to none only when the opacity would be equal to 0?
I have the following code:

```html
<slide class=“showing” :class=“{notshowing:!opened}”
  <div> Some text</div>
</slide>
```

And css

```css
.showing {
  display:flex
}

.notshowing {
  transition:2s;
  opacity:0
}
```

I have a carousel with too many slides, to get a clear image,e .g.on first slide I have 3 options, if I click on first option it throws me on the second  slide(after that I can comeback to the first slide by clicking on the button(carousel is styled that way that user cannot drag it)), second option to third slide etc.
so if I have too many options, it will take me different amount of time to get to different options. I came up only with one solution and it is to track by class the slide which I need(which option user click),hide the others, so that the number of slide for every option would be 1. However,if I instantly set display of slide to none, it would look awful. So that’s why I want to set opacity to 0 with transition when I leave the slide and then hide it

Comment: Aren't you missing `.showing` and `.notshowing` here? Also, please explain what you want to achieve with more details/visuals. If you want to keep the space of the element but make it invisible, you can use this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp Otherwise, the good ol' `display: none;` is nice.

Comment: The easiest and cleanest solution would be to look for another carousel package that suits your needs and is working properly. Will be far less hacky. There is a lot of various ones here: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#carousel

Comment: So after the animation ro transition turns an elements opacity to 0, you want the display to turn to none? If this is the case set up a timeout that has the same time frame as your transition and then set the elements display to none using javascript.

Comment: @kissu I am already using the vue-concise-carousel from that list. Couldn’t find a carousel which meets my needs,and,honestly, don’t think that such exists

Comment: You could sense the transitionend events rather than set a separate timer.